# flask-security make user always signed in

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

Im trying to make it so a specific  user is always logged in using the flask security extension.

I cant find any docs on this.
Can someone point me in the right direction to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings

> “Remember Me” functionality can be tricky to implement. However, Flask-Login makes it nearly transparent - just pass remember=True to
>   the login_user call. A cookie will be saved on the user’s computer,
>   and then Flask-Login will automatically restore the user ID from that
>   cookie if it is not in the session. The cookie is tamper-proof, so if
>   the user tampers with it (i.e. inserts someone else’s user ID in place
>   of their own), the cookie will merely be rejected, as if it was not
>   there.

```
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION
```

> The amount of time before the cookie expires, as a datetime.timedelta
>   object. Default: 365 days (1 non-leap Gregorian year)